# how to play music from SQL server using VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I am currently working on a project which is a music player but I am trying to make it work with SQL Server.

I have uploaded my music to SQL Server using queries , however the problem is retrieving them. The file type is varbinary(MAX). I tried to go an alternate route where i retrieve the binary in a text file and thereafter convert the file extension to .wav and play it through a media player while the local file being temporary.

```
Private Sub Online_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Try
        Using cn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Server= DESKTOP-8KB6RLJ; Database= TESTdb; Integrated security = true ")
            cn.Open()
            Using cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand()
                cmd.Connection = cn
                Dim qry As String
                qry = String.Format("SELECT FileStreamCol From MUSIC")
                cmd.CommandText = qry
                cmd.CommandTimeout = 0
                Dim oFileStream As System.IO.FileStream
                oFileStream = New System.IO.FileStream("C:\3N3RGY\bytes.mp3", System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate)
                Using myReader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
                    While (myReader.Read())
                        Dim data As Byte() = myReader(0)
                        oFileStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length)
                    End While
                    oFileStream.Close()
                    Dim myFiles As String()

                    myFiles = IO.Directory.GetFiles("C:\3N3RGY", "*.txt")

                    Dim newFilePath As String

                    For Each filepath As String In myFiles

                        newFilePath = filepath.Replace(".txt", ".mp3")

                        System.IO.File.Move(filepath, newFilePath)
                        AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = ListBox1.SelectedItem

                    Next
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using


    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Get the `Byte` array and call `File.WriteAllBytes`. If the data that you saved is valid, the file will be valid.

Comment: You are writing to a single `FileStream` in a `While` loop. If there are multiple `Byte` arrays then surely you should be saving each one to a different file. If there's only one, why the loop?

Comment: how would you do the while statement? and just to inform you , i have done a single conversion by manually changing the binary.txt file that was written to my computer as a .wav file and tried to play it using embedded wmp. that did not work. any suggestions?